# How to define locate control in Leaflet and Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, leaflet

I would like to define a locate control in my Leaflet Angular 2 project.
For now I have this code

```
ngOnInit() {
  let map = L.map("map", {
    center: [48.13, 11.57],
    zoom: 13,
    zoomControl: true,
    maxZoom: 30,
    minZoom: 8,
  }).addLayer(this.googleStreets);

  map.invalidateSize();

  map.locate({setView: true, maxZoom: 16, watch: true});

  L.control.scale().addTo(map);

  function onLocationFound(e) {
    var radius = e.accuracy/2;
    L.circle(e.latlng, radius).addTo(map);
   }

  map.on('locationfound', onLocationFound);

  }
```

The map searches location automatically and shows where user is.

I would like to add GPS icon thing to my map, like on the picture.
[image]

How could I implement this in Angular 2?

Comment: https://github.com/Asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet/blob/master/README.md

Comment: @ChauTran Sorry, but I do not see there anything bout GPS icon...Could you please tell me where it is there in documentation?

Comment: If by GPS Icon, you meant Marker then check out their Markers section in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the location that you got from the locationFound() function and add a new marker with that latlngs.